# Can't access Flask app running on 0.0.0.0 on GCE

Tags: python, flask, google-compute-engine

I set Firewall Rule for my local google compute instance at host '0.0.0.0' and port 7000.

And I executed `python server.py`, it was running on `https://0.0.0.0:7000`
but when I enter `https://external-ip:7000` on my local browser it did not work.

So how can I run flask on google compute engine and open in my local computer browser?

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return 'Hello World’

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=1,port=7000,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

Check your VPC firewall:

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls

In your terminal, see if connections are working locally on that host by issuing:

```
telnet localhost 7000
```

If it connects then it's either firewall or the below.

If you're running on https, you'll probably need to have something along the lines of:

```
context = ('host.crt', 'host.key')
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port='7000', ssl_context=context)
```

Lastly, it's https:// not \

Comment: when i tried telnet  on local host it said 'Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 7000: Connect failed'

Comment: It's probably iptables related, which you need to add an iptables rule to allow traffic on that port. `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` and
`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 7000 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`